# Error Plugin Activation in Wordpress: requires the GD library and its support library: libpng, libjpeg and FreeType 2

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently i'm facing an issue when install BotDetect Plugin to handle captcha for Contact Form 7 in Wordpress.

Error: BotDetect requires the GD library and its support library: libpng, libjpeg and FreeType 2
Checking all the requirements and it's all installed

PHPINFO()

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.36
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled


dpkg -l | grep libjpeg  //List shown
dpkg -l | grep libpng.  //List shown
dpkg -l | grep libfreetype. //List shown
```

Is there any other thing should be check ?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the basic PHP modules are enabled. You can view it here:
https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/server-environment/
in PHP Extensions
Some plugins do not show their requirements because these requirements are already contained in WordPress itself.
And one more moment. libfreetype and libfreetype2 are different libraries. Perhaps libfreetype2 is required